# Event calendar using jquery

Tags: jquery, calendar

I am using ##full event calendar##, when user  click on date, modal box will appearance and display details of the  events. I am using below code for full
Calendar. Any help appreciated

> ```
>  $(document).ready(function () { 
>         var date = new Date();
>         var d = date.getDate();
>         var m = date.getMonth();
>         var y = date.getFullYear();
>
>         $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
>             editable: true,
>             events: [
>                 {
>                     title: 'All Day Event',
>                     start: new Date(y, m, 1),
>
>                 },
>                 {
>                     title: 'Long Event',
>                     start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
>                     end: new Date(y, m, d-1)
>                 },
>                 {
>                     id: 999,
>                     title: 'Repeating Event',
>                     start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
>                     allDay: false
>                 },
>                 {
>                     id: 999,
>                     title: 'Repeating Event',
>                     start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
>                     allDay: false
>                 },
>                 {
>                     title: 'Meeting',
>                     start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
>                     allDay: false
>                 }
>             ]
>         });
>
>
> <div data-role="content">       
>             <div id='calendar'></div>
>         </div>
> ```

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: What to display event in modal box

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dayClick](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/) handler like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: [{
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, 1),

        }, {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
            end: new Date(y, m, d - 1)
        }, {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),
            allDay: false
        }, {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),
            allDay: false
        }, {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
            allDay: false
        }],
        dayClick: function (obj, event) {
            console.log('a day has been clicked!');
            console.log(moment(obj._d).format('DD MMM YYYY'), obj._d);
            //add your code to show the modal for the day obj._d here
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2bo6kqv5/)

Comment: Thanks for you answer arun, I tryed this but fail to obtain result

Comment: eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

        alert(calEvent.title);
       

    }